# TSLint - Disable alphabetical ordering of members

Tags: typescript, tslint

How can I disable alphabetical ordering of members in object literal syntax?

Example:

```
function receiveLogin(user) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    isFetching: false,
    isAuthenticated: true,
    id_token: user.id_token,
  };
}
```

I want to have the type as the first item.

Comment: The property to add to your `tslint.json` to disable this is right there in the error message.

Comment: Actually I am wondering why by default it's enabled. Such an annoying rule.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should have `"object-literal-sort-keys": false` in your `tslint.json` rules.

Example:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:latest",
  "rules": {
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to enable/disable this for a single object? I am afraid of possible side effects if I disable it across the entire application.